# How to build an armv71 (ARM32) docker container in Visual Studio 2022 containing a ASP.NET Core Web App?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, arm, armv7, .net-7.0

I'm working on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2022 and trying to create a simple ASP.NET Core Web App (.net 7.0) and put it into a docker image.
This docker image should be deployed onto an armv71 (ARM32) device (via tar archive).
When starting "Build Docker Image" it fails with following error:

```
...
error CTC1014: #12 [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "MyPlcDockerWebApp/MyPlcDockerWebApp.csproj"
 : error CTC1014: #12 sha256:353b0e08e28a4e967ad5c810f36eb6453202088e54405c3c2fb3cb70be70d3bf
 : error CTC1014: #12 9.885 Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 : error CTC1014: #12 9.888    at Regex1_Scan(RegexRunner, ReadOnlySpan`1)
 : error CTC1014: #12 9.888    at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.RunAllMatchesWithCallback[TState](String inputString, ReadOnlySpan`1 inputSpan, Int32 startat, TState& state, MatchCallback`1 callback, RegexRunnerMode mode, Boolean reuseMatchObject)
 : error CTC1014: #12 9.893 qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
 : error CTC1014: #12 9.921 Aborted
 : error CTC1014: #12 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "MyPlcDockerWebApp/MyPlcDockerWebApp.csproj"]: exit code: 134
 : error CTC1014: ------
 : error CTC1014:  > [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "MyPlcDockerWebApp/MyPlcDockerWebApp.csproj":
 : error CTC1014: ------
 : error CTC1014: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "MyPlcDockerWebApp/MyPlcDockerWebApp.csproj"]: exit code: 134
```

Sometimes I get this

```
error CTC1014: #12 [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "MyPlcDockerWebApp/MyPlcDockerWebApp.csproj"
 : error CTC1014: #12 sha256:7b86b8130fe749ac2390d652e6070685f81fc5ba8e51ca7d8fdf198580978932
 : error CTC1014: #12 5.024 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
 : error CTC1014: #12 5.044 Segmentation fault
 : error CTC1014: #12 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "MyPlcDockerWebApp/MyPlcDockerWebApp.csproj"]: exit code: 139
 : error CTC1014: ------
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0.4-jammy-arm32v7 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0.202-jammy-arm32v7 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyPlcDockerWebApp/MyPlcDockerWebApp.csproj", "MyPlcDockerWebApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyPlcDockerWebApp/MyPlcDockerWebApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyPlcDockerWebApp"
RUN dotnet build "MyPlcDockerWebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyPlcDockerWebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyPlcDockerWebApp.dll"]
```

What am I doing wrong?
I already tried different arm base images, but it didn't help.

On my windows machine it works (docker container gets build and started) fine when I use
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 as base image and
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 as build

Answer (score 0):

```
qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
```

QEMU is [not supported](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/7.0/supported-os.md#qemu) in recent dotnet versions:

> .NET 7 is not supported being run (emulated) via QEMU. QEMU is used, for example, to emulate Arm64 containers on x64, and vice versa.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to run dotnet under emulation. In your situation though, can you build your ASP.NET app on the host, generate cross-platform binaries (including all the dependencies) and include them into the docker image? Or do you also need to *run* your app under emulation?

Comment: Thanks for the info. 
However, when I replaced the dotnet sdk image with "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0" it worked as expected.